# Updating nullable column with NULL throws an error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datetime

I'm using Laravel framework v5.5 with MySQL database. I'm trying to create/update a record but get below error. The column published in my case is formatted as DATE and is nullable. However if I try to update the column with null then the error is thrown.

Request data:

```
{"id":4776,"name":"test","published":null}
```

Error:

```
  "message": "SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '' for column 'published' at row 1
```

I could of course remove the parameter published before its processed by MySQL, but then I have to do in many places, for this parameter and others as well. Another option would be to disable strict mode but I rather not do that. Any other options?

Comment: That's not a `NULL` value you're passing through, it's being introduced as an empty string, something completely different. Where is your insert code?

Comment: You were completely right- found that htmlspecialchars($published, ENT_QUOTES); replaced null to string. Thanks!

Comment: Please, please, *please* **DO NOT** use `htmlspecialchars` on database values. Ever. Use that only when displaying content in an HTML context. Keep your database content neutral and raw. Encode only when you know exactly where the content is going to be displayed. HTML, JSON, URI, and email all have different encodings, among others. Dictating HTML in your database creates a whole world of hurt, like "&amp;" showing up in email subject lines and other embarrassing gaffes.

Comment: I was thinking that its easier to sanitize it in db since I dont have to think of escaping it on all the different places data is shown. In terms of security that would be safer as well but yes It will probably cause alot of other problems.

Comment: Stick with me here: It's not easier! At all! It's not safer as you always, always need to pay attention to where you're using your data and escape accordingly if necessary. Laravel, if used properly and consistently, will have your back when it comes to escaping. If you try and be clever, you'll end up double-escaping or escaping for the wrong context.

Comment: @tadman is right about this. Don't ask me how I know; it's too embarrassing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're receiving a `null` value it's important to either propagate that as-is down to the Eloquent layer, or to scrub it from your parameters before it gets that far.

While database `NULL` is a valid value for a `DATETIME` column that *can* be `NULL`, empty string is not. Any form of casting from `null` to empty string is going to wreck things for you here.

Unless you specifically need to null out fields, scrubbing empty parameters is usually a good idea.